# java variable in printout function disappeared

Tags: java

```
public String getNOM(int i){
    String name = class_name.get(i);
    System.out.println(1+name);
    if(isHeritage(name)){
        System.out.println(3+name+ getGeneralization(name)==null);
        return Integer.toString(getGeneralization(name).getNOM());
    }
    return classes.get(i).getNOM();
}

public boolean isHeritage(String s){
    System.out.println(2+s+ getGeneralization(s)==null);
    return getGeneralization(s) != null;
}

public Generalization getGeneralization(String s){
    for(Generalization g : generalizations){
        if (g.getName().equals(s)) return g;
    }
    for(Generalization g: generalizations){
        return g.findSubClass(s);
    }
    return null;
}

public class Generalization{
   private String name;
   private List<Generalization> subClasses;

   public Generalization findSubClass(String s){        
     for(Generalization gen : subClasses){
        if(s.equals(gen.getName())) return gen;
        else gen.findSubClass(s);
     }
     return null;
   }
}
```

for a successful execution, the output should display

> 1String
>
> 2boolean
>
> 3boolean

but in my test, even i give a valid input, the output is:

> 1String
>
> false

so the number 2 in the 2nd printout and all 3rd printout are disappeared.
does anyone have idea why?

Thanks.

PS. Now it display correctly with code below, I think problem is my findSubClass function.

```
public boolean isHeritage(String s){
    System.out.println(2+s+ (getGeneralization(s)==null));
    return getGeneralization(s) != null;
}
```

Comment: Where is this false coming from?

Comment: Don't you have a NullPointerException (or any other RuntimeException) in the `getGeneralization(s)`call?

Where do the `false(which mean not null)` come from? Do you add it to the program output?

Comment: @SMA that is another function **getGeneralization(s)==null** which get Generalization with same name.

Comment: @Cidian yea, i added personnaly, I have corrected it to avoid confusion

Comment: can you paste the content of getGeneralization method.

Comment: @SMA I have added related content in the post

Comment: Voting to close; the question keeps changing. This is not a question, it's just "help me write this code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+` is evaluated before `==` is evaluated, which means you could have written

```
System.out.println((2+s+ getGeneralization(s))==null);
```

instead. To get the results as expected write

```
System.out.println(2+s+ (getGeneralization(s)==null));
```

However that won't print

```
2boolean
```

but

```
2Stringtrue
```

Obviously `getGeneralization(s)` returns `null`. Otherwise the third print would happen.

---

Your `findSubClass()` method does not seem to be correct either. (I assume you want to do a depth-first search for the subclass). It should look like this:

```
public Generalization findSubClass(String s){        
     for(Generalization gen : subClasses){
        if(s.equals(gen.getName())) return gen;
        else {
            Generalization subGen = gen.findSubClass(s);
            if (subGen != null)
                return subGen;
        }
     }
     return null;
}
```

Comment: @BroLegend: No, you just ignore the results of `gen.findSubClass(s)`.

Comment: thanks, I forgot to add return before gen.findsubclass.

Comment: @BroLegend: If you just add a `return` without checking for `null`, you don't search through all the subClasses, but only the *first*. Don't return anything until you found something or searched through *all* the subClasses.

Comment: first match or first any value (even null)?

Comment: @BroLegend: `null` means you haven't found the class yet. Since classes should have unique names, you'll find the class only once. But take a look at my answer. I added some code it. With my comment I just wanted to make sure that simply adding a `return` between `else` and `gen.findSubClass(s);` won't do the trick. In fact breaking from a loop in every case seldom makes sense, since you exit the loop after the first iteration.